# Convert complex comma-separated string into Python dictionary

Tags: python

I am getting following string format from csv file in Pandas

> "title = matrix, genre = action, year = 2000, rate = 8"

How can I change the string value into a python dictionary like this:

```
movie = "title = matrix, genre = action, year = 2000, rate = 8" 

movie = {
   "title": "matrix",   
   "genre": "action",   
   "year": "1964", 
   "rate":"8" 
}
```

Comment: `dict([s.split(' = ') for s in movie.split(', ')])`  I'm sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where do you get stuck when you try to write code for it?

Comment: Another needy and low-effort question from you Behseini. Thankfully readers are starting to notice, and they are voting accordingly (I have not voted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and then convert it into a dictionary.
A sample code is given below

```
movie = "title = matrix, genre = action, year = 2000, rate = 8"
movie = movie.split(",")
# print(movie)
tempMovie = [i.split("=") for i in movie]
movie = {}
for i in tempMovie:
    movie[i[0].strip()] = i[1].strip()
print(movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the solution you can use regex

```py
import re

input_user = "title = matrix, genre = action, year = 2000, rate = 8"

# Create a pattern to match the key-value pairs
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+) = ([\w,]+)" )

# Find all matches in the input string
matches = pattern.findall(input_user)

# Convert the matches to a dictionary
result = {key: value for key, value in matches}

print(result)
```

The result:

```
{'title': 'matrix,', 'genre': 'action,', 'year': '2000,', 'rate': '8'}
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
movie = "title = matrix, genre = action, year = 2000, rate = 8" 

dict_all_movies = {}

for idx in df.index:
    str_movie = df.at[idx, str_movie_column]
    movie_dict = dict(item.split(" = ") for item in str_movie.split(", ")) 
    dict_all_movies[str(idx)] = movie_dict
```